# cross origin on spring boot from chrome extension

Tags: javascript, spring, spring-boot, google-chrome-extension, cors

In my spring application, I have a method:

```
@CrossOrigin(origins="*")
@PostMapping("/datum")
Datum test(@RequestBody String data) {
    return repository.save(new Datum(data));
}
```

I want that all the application can access it, so I have put that **`@CrossOrigin(origins="/**")`**. But when I try to do so, it runs without any complain.

This is how I'm sending data from a chrome extension:

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
let url='http://localhost:8080/datum';
let data=JSON.stringify({ "data": body});
request.open('POST', url, true);
request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
request.send(data);
```

My extension manifest:

```
"permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "tabs",
    "<all_urls>",
    "background",
    "http://*/*",
    "https://*/*",
    "http://localhost:8080/datum"
],
```

Gives me error **403**

But client still can't access this, how this can be solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my `@SpringBootApplication` annoted class, I added this :

```
@Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry.addMapping("/**").allowedOrigins("*");
            }
        };
    }
```

And in `manifest.json`:

```
"permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "tabs",
    "background",
    "http://*/"
  ]
```

Now it works.