# How to allow all requests in spring boot enabled with CORS?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

In my *Spring boot* application, currently I have this class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class TestApplication {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SpringApplication.run(TestApplication.class, args);
   }
   @Bean
   public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
      return new WebMvcConfigurerAdapter() {
         @Override
         public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
            registry.addMapping("/user").allowedOrigins("http://localhost:3000");
         }
      };
   }
}
```

It just allow me to access or write from `http://localhost:3000`, but I want this rest method to be accessed by everything, like `http://localhost:1000` ~ `http://localhost:9999` or any site.

**How can I enable that ?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In my `@SpringBootApplication` annoted class, I added this :

```
@Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry.addMapping("/**").allowedOrigins("*");
            }
        };
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

It will be better if you create two APIs (controller) for each (one for reading and another for writing).
For write use this:

```
registry.addMapping("/user").allowedOrigins("http://localhost:3000");
//This will allow only calls from 3000 port to write
```

And for reading use this:

```
registry.addMapping("/user").allowedOrigins("http://localhost");
//This will allow reading via all ports.
```

Comment: all ports running on localhost, but what about all sites?

Comment: @MaifeeUlAsad You can use "*" for Access-Control-Allow-Origin to allow for all, but you need to decide at what level you want this. Check this for more info https://howtodoinjava.com/spring5/webmvc/spring-mvc-cors-configuration/

Comment: @MaifeeUlAsad Do you _really_ need every website to be able to access those endpoints? Are you aware of what CORS protect your site's users against? Have you considered the threads that you expose when you allow every third-party website to be able to access those endpoints?

Comment: @Ugnes see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58677342/10305444), it is giving me trouble for some reason, what can be the problem ?

Comment: @Ivar actually, I'm stuck in a project, so I'm opening up the whole system, maybe later i will configure them, in a better way. Can you take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58677342/10305444)

Answer (score 2):

Though you can do manually with other answers mentioned, you can simply achieve by annotation configuration as follows : after all, Spring is for convention over configuration.

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
@GetMapping("/users" )
```

However, be careful what you are saying by '*'. You are allowing every site that can access your endpoint. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

just add * in place of url

```
registry.addMapping("/user").allowedOrigins("*");
```

Answer (score 0):

you can enable CORS with a filter instead of Springboot security (no need to add any Dependency in pom.xml) :

```
@Order(-1)  
@Component
public class SimpleCORSFilter implements Filter {


    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;


//        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", request.getHeader("Origin"));
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"); // * = all domainName
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true"); // allow CrossDomain to use Origin Domain
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT"); 
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600"); // Preflight cache duration in browser
//        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept, X-Requested-With, remember-me"); 
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*"); // all header

        chain.doFilter(req, res);
    }

}
```

Springboot security also uses Filter. See reference: [filter](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-handlerinterceptor-vs-filter#key-differences-and-use-cases)